# Django Logging - Log File from Handler Not Found

Tags: django, apache, logging

I have logging set up in my Django project. It works locally in development but it causing trouble in production. `settings.py` bits are as follows:

```
import os

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))

. . .

'handlers': {
    'log_file': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'logs/django.log'),
        'maxBytes': '16777216',
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    },

. . .
```

I keep getting this error in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'log_file': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/logs/django.log'
```

I've tested this in the Django shell by running the code and setting `PROJECT_PATH` manually and it seems to return the correct path. Plus, I've checked and checked the permissions on the log file. Although unnecessary, I changed it to `777` just to test. Still no luck.

My local log fills up with all that I expect while the production log is empty.

In thinking about this, I suppose this log location is probably not the best, but if it worked in production, at least I'd know... Then, I could work on changing the location.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the path `'/logs/django.log'` valid and writeable by the user?

Comment: The Apache user is `www-data`, the ownership is `root:www-data` and permissions are set to `775`, currently. But I have tested with different ownership and `777` permissions, as indicated in the original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I would really like to get an answer to this, I have decided to take another approach so I can move on. It seems this question is not spurring enough attention and I don't feel like a bounty right now, so I disabled logging to a file for now. I am going to redesign my approach anyway, so this seems like a decent idea.

What I came up with temporarily that seems to work and not give errors is this (for the file handler definition):

```
'file': {
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
    'filename': '/some/fixed/path/to/logs/django.log',
},
```

Note that before I was using a value derived from `os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'logs/django.log')`. Not sure why this didn't work, but it was the culprit. So even though this bit was correct: `PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))` (even confirmed in the python shell), it wasn't working in production.

Comment: I've run into the same problem.  Were you running in embedded or daemon mode?

Comment: Not in daemon mode... It seems whenever I go from development to my Apache server (with `mod_wsgi`), I run into this problem. Funny thing is, I always suspect permissions first, and fix those to no avail... I think it has to do with my paths. I generally set up something like `PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))` and use this in all my paths. It's probably due to my server configuration.

Comment: Did you find anything? I have the same config. My configuration runs using python server but when I switch to Apache it goes down.

Comment: I no longer use Apache. My stack is using uWSGI and Nginx. Much simpler and logging is all good. After years struggling with Apache, I finally abandoned it. Apologies I couldn't be more helpful.