# Heroku App Crashed Django

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Django website onto Heroku but when I load my site, I get this error:

> Application Error:
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served.   Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

So I type `heroku logs` and this is what I got:

```
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361800+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361809+00:00 app[web.1]:     return  util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361801+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361803+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361805+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361808+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361811+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361815+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361817+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361812+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361819+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361814+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/django_test/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361818+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361823+00:00 app[web.1]:     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361821+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361822+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361829+00:00 app[web.1]:     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361830+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'default': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/logs/mylog.log'
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361929+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-02-20 15:49:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361825+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361828+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 576, in configure
2015-02-20T15:49:36.361826+00:00 app[web.1]:       dictConfigClass(config).configure()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488086+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488087+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488090+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi =  self.app.wsgi()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488092+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488093+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488089+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488103+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/django_test/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488099+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488100+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488101+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488082+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-02-20 15:49:36 +0000]  [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488076+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/static/
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488084+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488106+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488108+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488131+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 576, in configure
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488111+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488113+00:00 app[web.1]:     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488095+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488133+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'default': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/logs/mylog.log'
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488140+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488136+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488096+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488141+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488143+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488097+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488148+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488104+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488153+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/django_test/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488110+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488158+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488157+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488160+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488150+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488107+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488151+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488163+00:00 app[web.1]:     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488114+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488132+00:00 app[web.1]:     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488129+00:00 app[web.1]:     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488164+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488165+00:00 app[web.1]:     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488168+00:00 app[web.1]:     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488139+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488135+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488137+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488167+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 576, in configure
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507131+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507076+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 189, in run
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488146+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488144+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507001+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2015-02-20T15:49:36.506915+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-20T15:49:36.506970+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507154+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507531+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507476+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in handle_chld
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507269+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488147+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488154+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488171+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-02-20 15:49:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507190+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507453+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507056+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507382+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 338, in stop
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507715+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488161+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488170+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'default': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/logs/mylog.log'
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507292+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 293, in halt
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507213+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 197, in run
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507642+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507358+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
2015-02-20T15:49:36.488155+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
2015-02-20T15:49:36.506923+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2015-02-20T15:49:36.507554+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 455, in reap_workers
2015-02-20T15:49:37.304329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2015-02-20T15:49:37.292485+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-02-20T15:49:36.299215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-02-20T15:49:42.613930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=article-django.herokuapp.com request_id=5e18c64f-98b1-4f2b-a88b-c9d93a0908e9 fwd="173.3.238.36" dyno=web.1 connect=5001ms service= status=503 bytes=
```

I looked at this log and it seems like the main problem is something with `'/app/logs/mylog.log'` not existing. If that's the case, how I do I create that file?

Edit: Here is the LOGGING section of my settings.py file:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins':{
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'email_backend': 
    'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
             'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
             'level': 'ERROR',
             'propogate': True,
         },
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21763248) could be of help?

Comment: @chridam: But I'm not sure I have an Apache server on my Ubuntu machine. How can I determine if such a server is installed?

Comment: Not so sure how you can go about that sorry, I just bumped into that similar solution and thought it might give you pointers. This on the other hand may be closer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20983546/

Comment: Check out the section in the Django docs on logging configuration.  Without knowing more about your folder structure and setup, I can't help much more but hopefully this will point you in the right direction: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Comment: Happy to help troubleshoot if you would like to direct message me

Answer (score 0):

`/app` is directory in which your application is put on Heroku. Try to add `logs` directory in root of your project and push it to Heroku - directory will then exist so log file should be created without problems.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? Which file would I add `logs` to. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Don't add any files - in your project create directory named `logs` and add it to git repo. Then push changes to Heroku. This new directory will be cloned on Heroku under `/app/logs` path and then I assume there will be no problems with automatic creation of `mylog.log` file which seems to be main problem here.

Comment: `mylog.log` wasn't created apparently because my site still doesn't work and I get the same Traceback. I did `mkdir logs`. Then I did `git add logs`, `git commit -m "Created directory", and `git push heroku master` but I got `Everything is up-to-date`. Yet when I refreshed my site page, I got the same application error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hmm try to create any file in `logs` directory, add it to repo and push again - maybe Heroku's git doesn't take empty directory as a valid change.

Comment: That error went away so thank you for that, but now I have a new error: `ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'django_request': Unable to add handler 'request_handler': 'request_handler'`. See my settings.py code that I just posted in the original post.

Comment: I wonder if it make sense to talk about this new error here as it's not related with ability to create a logfile.

However - either here or anywhere else - besides settings.py many help would give full stacktrace - we don't know what is throwing this error without it.

Comment: I made a new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678703/valueerror-unable-to-configure-logger-django-request-unable-to-add-handler