# ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'django_request': Unable to add handler 'request_handler': 'request_handler'

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Django site onto Heroku but I get:

```
Application Error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.  Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I ran `heroku logs` and this is my full stacktrace:

```
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259352+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259353+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259358+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259356+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259359+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259361+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259364+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259365+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/django_test/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259362+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259375+00:00 app[web.1]:     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259366+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259371+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259373+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259376+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259372+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259368+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259384+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-02-23 15:53:34 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.263948+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/static/
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259379+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 627, in configure
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270683+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259369+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270675+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270681+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259377+00:00 app[web.1]:     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270693+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270690+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270592+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-02-23 15:53:34 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270598+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270679+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270697+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259380+00:00 app[web.1]:     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270699+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-02-23T15:53:34.259382+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'django_request': Unable to add handler 'request_handler': 'request_handler'
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270709+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270707+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
 2015-02-23T15:53:34.270695+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270701+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270711+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270688+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270716+00:00 app[web.1]:     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270715+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270732+00:00 app[web.1]:     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270685+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270734+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 627, in configure
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270705+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270739+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270737+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'django_request': Unable to add handler 'request_handler': 'request_handler'
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270738+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270713+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270744+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270703+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/django_test/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270719+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270741+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270746+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270735+00:00 app[web.1]:     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270751+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270753+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270749+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270755+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270742+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270762+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270766+00:00 app[web.1]:     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270756+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/django_test/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270759+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270763+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270772+00:00 app[web.1]:     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270769+00:00 app[web.1]:     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270760+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270770+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 627, in configure
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270745+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270767+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270748+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297494+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270775+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-02-23 15:53:34 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297732+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297484+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297561+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297530+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297607+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270752+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270757+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.298282+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297688+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297774+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 197, in run
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297856+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 293, in halt
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297832+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297946+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 338, in stop
2015-02-23T15:53:34.298042+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in handle_chld
2015-02-23T15:53:34.298097+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.298121+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 455, in reap_workers
2015-02-23T15:53:34.298215+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270764+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297751+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2015-02-23T15:53:34.270773+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'django_request': Unable to add handler 'request_handler': 'request_handler'
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297632+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 189, in run
2015-02-23T15:53:34.297922+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()             2015-02-23T15:53:34.298017+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2015-02-23T15:53:35.396979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-02-23T15:53:35.409095+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-23T16:23:40.843143+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=article-django.herokuapp.com request_id=6035ffff-0fbe-40b3-b817-50bd8a2e57ce fwd="173.3.238.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-23T16:23:41.044252+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=article-django.herokuapp.com request_id=86b1f5ff-aa91-43cf-9481-76e06fc54837 fwd="173.3.238.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

This is my `LOGGING` section of my `settings.py` file:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins':{
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'email_backend': 
    'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
             'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
             'level': 'ERROR',
             'propogate': True,
         },
    }
}
```

So how do I go about adding `request_handler`? In my `settings.py` file or somewhere else in my project? I'd appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you.

Edit: This is my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn django_test.wsgi
```

This is my new stacktrace after commenting out the `LOGGING` section:

```
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756819+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756799+00:00 app[web.1]:     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756826+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756811+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756821+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756825+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756832+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756830+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756809+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756833+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756823+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763420+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756838+00:00 app[web.1]:     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763487+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763471+00:00 app[web.1]:     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756843+00:00 app[web.1]:     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756845+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'django_request': Unable to add handler 'request_handler': 'request_handler'
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763438+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763447+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756828+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/django_test/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763415+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756841+00:00 app[web.1]:     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756816+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763450+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763422+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756842+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 627, in configure
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763494+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763506+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763453+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763446+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756829+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763412+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763413+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763443+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763455+00:00 app[web.1]:     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763488+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856271+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763509+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856019+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763495+00:00 app[web.1]:     return  self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756836+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756835+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763515+00:00 app[web.1]:     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763456+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856292+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in handle_chld
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763498+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763517+00:00 app[web.1]:     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763449+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763440+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763417+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763468+00:00 app[web.1]:     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763501+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763519+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'django_request': Unable to add handler 'request_handler': 'request_handler'
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763497+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763469+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 627, in configure
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763505+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
2015-02-23T17:53:25.855770+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756839+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763499+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763490+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763452+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763485+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763419+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.855879+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 189, in run
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763444+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/django_test/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-02-23T17:53:25.756873+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-02-23 17:53:25 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763482+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Unable to configure logger 'django_request': Unable to add handler 'request_handler': 'request_handler'
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763508+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856457+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763484+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763503+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763502+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/django_test/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763513+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
2015-02-23T17:53:25.855939+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763512+00:00 app[web.1]:     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763404+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-02-23 17:53:25 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763525+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-02-23 17:53:25 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.855802+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763510+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
2015-02-23T17:53:25.855859+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763408+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-23T17:53:25.855961+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856205+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 338, in stop
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856371+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 455, in reap_workers
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856348+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763516+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 627, in configure
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856041+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 197, in run
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763410+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856532+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2015-02-23T17:53:25.855664+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-23T17:53:25.855710+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763441+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856111+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 293, in halt
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763491+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-02-23T17:53:25.763492+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856088+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2015-02-23T17:53:25.856178+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
2015-02-23T17:53:26.778703+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-23T17:53:26.762631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-02-23T17:53:38.945408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=article-django.herokuapp.com request_id=99a1609e-5870-4dd9-972a-c7d6404a12f3 fwd="173.3.238.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-23T17:53:39.134485+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=article-django.herokuapp.com request_id=7dcdfb81-9e0a-447b-813a-0b4d4a40b962 fwd="173.3.238.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: What is your `Procfile` ? Do you have any custom `gunicorn` configuration? Try to remove all `LOGGING` section from `settings.py` and see what happen - it can tell us if there is some conflict or misconfiguration.

Comment: See `Procfile` above

Comment: I did that change you said but I only got an `ImportError`.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this (about Procfile), then went to actually test this in my test app and noticed it failed. I must accidently post this and I deleted it ;)

Your Procfile seems fine. Can you try my other advices - comment out whole LOGGING section from Django settings - maybe there is some weird conflict. Last thing that comes to my mind here is wsgi file - maybe there is something weird there

Comment: I posted the new stacktrace. But I still get the same ValueError. What do you think could be wrong with the wsgi file?

Comment: @brown1001 hey buddy! Did you found any solution?